# How to use Julia code in my Latex document?

Tags: luatex, julia, ffi

according to https://towardsdatascience.com/5-ways-julia-is-better-than-python-334cc66d64ae it says (under item 2) the following

```
  Julia code is universally executable in R, Latex, Python, and C.
```

I googled a little bit and could not find an example of how to do this. of course one would need to have [Julia](https://julialang.org/) itself installed on one's PC in addition to TexLive.

I am not talking about listing Julia code in Latex of course. Or about using Latex inside Julia.

The above says `Julia code executable in Latex`, which for me, means one can write some Julia function and call it from Latex and get the result back. Same as using Lua from Lualatex now. And the same when calling Python from Latex.

At least this is how I read the above.

If so, could we have a very small example of how to do this?

For starter, here is a MWE I wrote sometime ago about using Python in Latex

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
  \usepackage{pythontex}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{pyconsole}
  x = 987.27
  x = x**2
  \end{pyconsole}

  The variable is $x=\pycon{x}$
  \end{document}
```

Which needs to be compiled like this:

```
  pdflatex foo.tex
  /usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/pythontex  foo.tex
  pdflatex foo.tex
```

How to do something similar to the above for Julia?

Comment: Is LuaTeX possible?  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/504230/10995

Comment: @HenriMenke yes ofcourse. When I said inside Latex, I meant in any way. I actually myself just use LuaTex only.

Comment: Well, if I read it correctly, the article also talks about the need to have a wrapper for that. Which you have identified as pythontex. I dont use Julia, just Python and R; sadly never had rason to look at it.

Comment: @TomášKruliš  Yes, I would expect there is a need for a package/wrapper of some sort for Julia as well. The package `pythontex` I used in the example, is needed when calling Python from Latex.

Comment: It also has support for Julia. I dont exactly know to which extend, but I would expect to actually full extend; since R support in `pythontex` is "basic"; but actally everything works :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Julia has a C-API which you can use in LuaTeX via FFI.  It requires some boilerplate code where you repeat some function prototypes from the [API](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/src/jlapi.c) and some wrappers to convert between C types and Lua types.  This is actually pretty painless.  Save this file as `julia.lua` in the same directory as your document.

**`julia.lua`**

```lua
local ffi = require("ffi")
local JULIA = ffi.load("julia", true)

ffi.cdef [[
// Types
typedef struct _jl_value_t jl_value_t;

// Initialization
void jl_init__threading(void);
void jl_init_with_image__threading(const char *julia_bindir,
                                   const char *image_relative_path);

// Execution and conversion
jl_value_t *jl_eval_string(const char*);
const char *jl_string_ptr(jl_value_t *);
const char *jl_typeof_str(jl_value_t *);
]]

local julia_initialized = false

local julia = {}

function julia.init(rpath)
    -- Initialize the Julia interpreter (singleton)
    if not julia_initialized then
        if rpath then
            JULIA.jl_init_with_image__threading(rpath, "sys.so")
        else
            JULIA.jl_init__threading()
        end
        julia_initialized = true
    end
end

function julia.run(expr)
    assert(julia_initialized)
    JULIA.jl_eval_string(expr)
end

function julia.eval(expr)
    assert(julia_initialized)
    local jlval, cstr, str
    jlval = JULIA.jl_eval_string(expr)
    -- First check that the datatype
    if jlval ~= ffi.NULL then
        cstr = JULIA.jl_typeof_str(jlval)
    else
        return nil
    end
    if cstr ~= ffi.NULL then
        str = ffi.string(cstr)
    else
        return nil
    end
    -- if the datatype is string, convert to Lua string
    if str == "String" then
        cstr = JULIA.jl_string_ptr(jlval)
    else
        return nil
    end
    if cstr ~= ffi.NULL then
        str = ffi.string(cstr)
    else
        return nil
    end
    return str
end

return julia
```

You can now use this module in your document via `require("julia")`.  It provides three functions:

1. `julia.init(rpath)` This function has to be called once before the other functions to initialize the interpreter.  Depending on your installation it might be necessary to provide the runtime path of Julia as the argument `rpath` (see also [Calling Julia from Lua](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504230/calling-julia-from-lua)).  In my installation this is not necessary and I can just omit the argument.
2. `julia.run(expr)` Just runs `expr`.
3. `julia.eval(expr)` This also runs the expression `expr` but attempts convert the last value of `expr` to string and returns it.

The Julia code you pass to this should be error-free, because there is not checking for errors on the Julia level.  I don't know whether interpreter just bails if it sees an error, but this would also crash your document compilation.

Here I wrap the `julia.eval` function into some TeX-specific argument scanning and printing and assign it to a macro called `\directjulia` which can be used similar to `\directlua`.  The big bonus of this over things like `pythontex` is that everything is fully expandable.  You have to process the document with `--shell-escape`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
julia = require("julia")
julia.init()

local t = lua.get_functions_table()
t[#t + 1] = function()
    local expr = token.scan_string()
    local str = julia.eval(expr)
    if str then
        tex.sprint(str)
    end
end
token.set_lua("directjulia", #t, "global")
\end{luacode*}
\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
julia.run[===[
x = [1 2 3]'
A = [1 0 1; 0 1 1; 1 1 0]

y = x'*A*x
]===]
\end{luacode*}

\edef\value{\directjulia{string(y[1])}}

\texttt{\meaning\value}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I also have a Gist on GitHub with boilerplate for a couple of other scripting languages: https://gist.github.com/hmenke/2d57a3aa1d3d59a265f935dd4b384c36

Comment: At the gist page on top, theres written about LuaJIT. So does this require LuaJIT compiler, or is only current LuaTeX sufficient? Thank you for clarification.

Comment: @TomášKruliš The FFI is originally a feature of LuaJIT and is not present in PUC-Rio Lua.  However, a FFI that is compatible with the one from LuaJIT is embedded in LuaTeX.

Comment: Trying to running your solution with 64bit LuaLaTeX and current Julia win64 instalation I am getting error: `a:2: could not load library julia
stack traceback:
 [C]: in function 'FFISUPPORTED'
 ./julia.lua:2: in main chunk
 [C]: in function 'require'
 [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }
                                                  
l.36 \end{luacode*}`. I have `julia.lua` in project directory. I have fresh installs of Julia and TeXlive 2020 in my PATH. What I could be doing wrong? Are there any other JUlia modules that I have to have?

Comment: My error message is simillar to this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515624/where-does-ffi-load-look-for-dynamic-libraries-by-default-in-texlive?rq=1 This was resolved by adding additional module. I dont know how to apply that solution here. I am on Win10.

Comment: @TomášKruliš No idea, sorry.  I don't run Windows and I have no idea how DSO loading works there.

Comment: OK. Even theoretically, are you familiar with Windows Subsystem for Linux (wiki link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)? Could your solution work through this feature? I have hard time learning Linux. But its great that through this WSL everything works :) Only think required is to prepend before any `bash` or other command `wsl` (example: `wsl perl myscript.pl`) and deal with pathing. In your answer, I dont identify any "cmdline command" per se; and only pathing variable is `rpath`, is that correct?

Comment: With `wsl` and `luajit` your examples work even on Windows, expcept for actual `julia.lua`; which errors because it cannot find `libjulia.so` (which is in `/opt/julias/julia/lib`).

Answer (score 2):

PythonTeX officially supports Julia almost out of the box. You only need to explicitly say that you want to use Julia, just to avoid naming conflicts. Here an MWE.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[usefamily={julia,jl}]{pythontex}

\begin{document}
    \begin{jlcode} % Or {juliacode}
        α = 23.15;
        α² = α^2;
    \end{jlcode}

    % To print it to LaTeX, `print()` directly from Julia or use `\jl` or `\julia`:
    $ \alpha^2 = \jl{α²} $!
\end{document}
```

And compile with (or any engine):

```
xelatex document.tex
pythontex document.tex
xelatex document.tex
```

I think it's not necessary to say you need Julia installed and accessible from your system. Unfortunately, for this reason, it'll not work on Overleaf.

Read [the docs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pythontex/pythontex.pdf) to see more details.